# Bazel build file introspection

Tags: bazel

Are there any tools out there for introspecting a collection of Bazel build files to run queries against a codebase with? I'm thinking of a simple case of collecting all defined tags used in a codebase. Some sort of bazel metaquery sort of capability that will let me scope out the conventions and usages across a repo with a substantial amount of build files.

It would even be nice to be able to do a cross tabulation of `cc_test` and `py_test` rules against their collective tags. Ideally there'd be a python client to introspect the bazel files.

Comment: There is the bazel query functionality:
https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html

Comment: Would the idea be something analogous to a graphql query where I pull in all the itemized hits from the query and it's up to me to roll that data up into something more telling? That could be tenable given I can target arbitrary constructs in the startlark/bazel syntax, which from a quick glance seems to cover a large fraction of the bases according to the set of possible query [functions](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html#functions). I'm not yet fully acquainted with bazel yet to think of a counter example of something I couldn't query that's defined in a bazel file.

Comment: Maybe another way to put it is to find some way to jump into a starlark [interpreter](https://github.com/bazelbuild/starlark#overview) session and go at it with `type` and `dir` commands much like one would do in Python loading up modules and poking around. I'm not sure what the analogous entrypoint for loading a buildfile would be once in that session but its an intriguing thought.

Comment: I'm wondering if the `load` [statement](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/build-ref.html#load) is a good example of something outside the reach of a bazel query; eg find all build files that load a particular symbol, something along those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`bazel query` provides information about your target dependency graph, with a highly expressive query language. It can output into various formats like DOT, XML, Protobuf, and the text representation of the expanded BUILD files themselves (if there are macros) for post-processing. See: [Bazel query how-to](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query-how-to.html), [Bazel query reference](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/query.html).

`bazel cquery` does the same as `query`, but also performs the analysis phase, which computes information about configurations (e.g. CPU, API levels) over the target dependency graph. This takes slightly longer, but gives you a more accurate representation of the graph that Bazel brings the execution phase. See: [Bazel cquery reference](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/cquery.html).

`bazel aquery` is not directly related to BUILD file introspections in that it presents information about executable actions, which is a few layers of computation after BUILD file parsing and analysis. See: [Bazel aquery reference](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/aquery.html)

`query`, `cquery` and `aquery` don't operate on the syntax of the BUILD files. If you want to work with the Starlark syntax / AST, check out the `buildozer` and `buildifier` tooling in the [bazelbuild/buildtools](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools) repository.

If there are information about your build graph that cannot be retrieved using these mechanisms, please file a feature request on the Bazel GitHub project.

Comment: Very interesting, looks like all these `buildtools` are primarily written in `go` and that buildifier and buildozer do give great examples of building upon the basic starlark lexing and parsing functionality defined in https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/tree/master/build. Looks like to do my build file analysis I'll need to pick up some `go` skills.

Comment: Found this lil nugget, https://github.com/google/starlark-go, which when I search for starlark imports under buildtools I found this beauty [buildifier2.go](https://github.com/bazelbuild/buildtools/blob/master/buildifier2/buildifier2.go). There's a wonderful docstring there _...use the AST from go.starlark.net/syntax. This will give us a much more precise AST and will allow us to share code with the Skylark interpreter. The end goal is to build a number of tools able to **parse, analyze**, format, refactor, evaluate Skylark code._